Camera permission exception on iOS in flutter project
I keep getting the following exception in flutter when I try to open the ReaderWidget of this example from the zxing library:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel: "dev.flutter.pigeon.camera_avfoundation.CameraApi.getAvailableCameras".)
#0      AVFoundationCamera.availableCameras (package:camera_avfoundation/src/avfoundation_camera.dart:76:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _ReaderWidgetState.initStateAsync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_zxing/src/ui/reader_widget.dart:199:29)
<asynchronous suspension>

The following part throws the exception (github link to package):
  @override
  Future<List<CameraDescription>> availableCameras() async {
    try {
      return (await _hostApi.getAvailableCameras())
          // See comment in messages.dart for why this is safe.
          .map((PlatformCameraDescription? c) => c!)
          .map(cameraDescriptionFromPlatform)
          .toList();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      throw CameraException(e.code, e.message);
    }
  }

A similar exception occurs, when I try to access the media library.
What I found is that I have to add the following lines to the info.plist, which I did:
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need photo library access to scan barcodes</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need to access your camera for scanning QR codes</string>

When I open XCode -> Runner -> Runner -> Info I also see the entries listed and afterwords I did successfully flutter build ios.
Also, I am never prompted to grant access when I use the app. I just open the screen where the camera should be and see the error.
When I download and install the example, everything works as expected. The popup appears and I see the "Camera" option in the Settings for the app in my phone. I also tried copying the Info.plist of the example 1:1, but it also does not help.
Any ideas how to get the permissions working, or what additional steps I have to take to request the permission?
Here is the Code of my component:

class SetupStepScanQrCode extends StatefulWidget {
  final SetupStepperWidget setupStepper;

  const SetupStepScanQrCode(this.setupStepper, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SetupStepScanQrCode> createState() => SetupStepScanQrCodeState();
}

class SetupStepScanQrCodeState extends State<SetupStepScanQrCode> {
  late final SetupStepperWidget setupStepper;
  Uint8List? createdCodeBytes;

  Code? result;
  Codes? multiResult;

  bool isMultiScan = false;

  bool showDebugInfo = true;
  int successScans = 0;
  int failedScans = 0;

  bool isManualProcess = false;
  bool qrCodeScanned = false;
  String? deviceName;
  String? devicePassword;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupStepper = widget.setupStepper;
  }

  void setDeviceDetails(name, password) {
    deviceName = name;
    devicePassword = password;
  }

  void connect() {
    setupStepper.setDeviceDetails(deviceName, devicePassword);
    setupStepper.next();
  }

  Future<Widget> _initializeReaderWidget() async {
    try {
      return ReaderWidget(
        onScan: _onScanSuccess,
        onScanFailure: _onScanFailure,
        onMultiScan: _onMultiScanSuccess,
        onMultiScanFailure: _onMultiScanFailure,
        onMultiScanModeChanged: _onMultiScanModeChanged,
        onControllerCreated: _onControllerCreated,
        isMultiScan: isMultiScan,
        scanDelay: Duration(milliseconds: isMultiScan ? 50 : 500),
        resolution: ResolutionPreset.high,
        lensDirection: CameraLensDirection.back,
        flashOnIcon: const Icon(Icons.flash_on),
        flashOffIcon: const Icon(Icons.flash_off),
        flashAlwaysIcon: const Icon(Icons.flash_on),
        flashAutoIcon: const Icon(Icons.flash_auto),
        galleryIcon: const Icon(Icons.photo_library),
        toggleCameraIcon: const Icon(Icons.switch_camera),
        actionButtonsBackgroundBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        actionButtonsBackgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return Center(child: Text('Error initializing camera (caught).'));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isCameraSupported = defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android;

    return BaseLayout(
      stepTitle,
      SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<Widget>(
              future: _initializeReaderWidget(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    // Display error message or a fallback UI
                    return Center(
                        child: Text(
                            'Error initializing camera (snapshot.hasError)'));
                  }
                  // Return the ReaderWidget or error widget if no error
                  return snapshot.data!;
                } else {
                  // Return a loading indicator while waiting for the future to complete
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
            if (showDebugInfo)
              DebugInfoWidget(
                successScans: successScans,
                failedScans: failedScans,
                error: isMultiScan ? multiResult?.error : result?.error,
                duration: isMultiScan
                    ? multiResult?.duration ?? 0
                    : result?.duration ?? 0,
                onReset: _onReset,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      description: stepDescription,
      content: Column(
        children: stepContent,
      ),
    );
  }

  String get stepTitle {
    if (isManualProcess) {
      return 'Bluetoothverbindung herstellen';
    }
    return 'Scan QR-Code';
  }

  String get stepImage {
    if (isManualProcess) {
      return manualSetupBluetooth;
    }
    return cameraPlaceholder;
  }

  String get stepDescription {
    if (isManualProcess) {
      return '';
    }
    return 'Hier eine Anleitung.';
  }

  List<Widget> get stepContent {
    if (isManualProcess) {
      return [SetupStepSubBluetooth(this)];
    }
    return [
      qrCodeScanned
          ? Text(
              'QR-Code erkannt',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .displayMedium!
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
            )
          : Text(
              'Kein QR-Code vorhanden?',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .displaySmall!
                  .copyWith(color: const Color(0xFF7C7C7C)),
            ),
      SizedBox(height: qrCodeScanned ? paddingMain * 2 : paddingMain / 2),
      qrCodeScanned
          ? FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // TODO: Disable if devicename and password are empty
                connect();
              },
              child: const Text('Jetzt verbinden'),
            )
          : OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isManualProcess = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Manuelle Eingabe starten'),
            ),
    ];
  }

  void _onControllerCreated(_, Exception? error) {
    if (error != null) {
      // Handle permission or unknown errors
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: $error');
    }
  }

  _onScanSuccess(Code? code) {
    setState(() {
      successScans++;
      result = code;
    });
  }

  _onScanFailure(Code? code) {
    setState(() {
      failedScans++;
      result = code;
    });
    if (code?.error?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: ${code?.error}');
    }
  }

  _onMultiScanSuccess(Codes codes) {
    setState(() {
      successScans++;
      multiResult = codes;
    });
  }

  _onMultiScanFailure(Codes result) {
    setState(() {
      failedScans++;
      multiResult = result;
    });
    if (result.codes.isNotEmpty == true) {
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: ${result.codes.first.error}');
    }
  }

  _onMultiScanModeChanged(bool isMultiScan) {
    setState(() {
      this.isMultiScan = isMultiScan;
    });
  }

  _showMessage(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
    );
  }

  _onReset() {
    setState(() {
      successScans = 0;
      failedScans = 0;
    });
  }
}

Here is my Info.plist (that - according to XCode -> Targets Runner -> Build Settings -> Info.plist File is used in debug, profile and release)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>COMPANY Myapplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>myapplication</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>auth0</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our app uses Bluetooth to configure your WiFi credentials.</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need photo library access to scan barcodes</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need to access your camera for scanning QR codes</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


Would it be helpful https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera ?

How do you try to get permission from the user to access the camera?

I don't do anything specific, I use the descired reader widget of the package, which does the camera-access in this line, which is exactly the line that throws.

@marks : issue is resolved or still there?

After all it turned out that someone had added a dependency in the pubspec.yaml file a long time ago and the dependency was no longer valid or used as intended. We did not receive any errors, but it turned out to block all permission requests of the application ...

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>We need camera access for your profile picture and identity verification, boosting account security and personalizing your experience.</string>

I tried using your example code in my implementation, below is my podfile:
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

# Enable use_frameworks! and use_modular_headers!
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
              '$(inherited)',
               'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
               'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1'
            ]
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      # Disable bridging headers for module interfaces
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_MODULE_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME'] = ''
    end
  end
end

And here is my example.dart file:
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zxing/flutter_zxing.dart';

class ScanResultWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScanResultWidget({
    super.key,
    this.result,
    this.onScanAgain,
  });

  final Code? result;
  final Function()? onScanAgain;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              result?.format?.name ?? '',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              result?.text ?? '',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Inverted: ${result?.isInverted}\t\tMirrored: ${result?.isMirrored}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: onScanAgain,
              child: const Text('Scan Again'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DebugInfoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DebugInfoWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.successScans,
    required this.failedScans,
    this.error,
    this.duration = 0,
    this.onReset,
  });

  final int successScans;
  final int failedScans;
  final String? error;
  final int duration;

  final Function()? onReset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle? style =
    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black54,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('Success: $successScans', style: style),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text('Failed: $failedScans', style: style),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text('Duration: $duration ms', style: style),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: onReset,
                  child: const Text('Reset'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnsupportedPlatformWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnsupportedPlatformWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'This platform is not supported yet.',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      ),
    );
  }
}


class BarEx extends StatefulWidget {
  const BarEx({super.key});

  @override
  State<BarEx> createState() => _BarExState();
}

class _BarExState extends State<BarEx> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Zxing Example',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DemoPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoPage> createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  Uint8List? createdCodeBytes;

  Code? result;
  Codes? multiResult;

  bool isMultiScan = false;

  bool showDebugInfo = true;
  int successScans = 0;
  int failedScans = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isCameraSupported = defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android;
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Scan Code'),
              Tab(text: 'Create Code'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            if (kIsWeb)
              const UnsupportedPlatformWidget()
            else if (!isCameraSupported)
              const Center(
                child: Text('Camera not supported on this platform'),
              )
            else if (result != null && result?.isValid == true)
                ScanResultWidget(
                  result: result,
                  onScanAgain: () => setState(() => result = null),
                )
              else
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    ReaderWidget(
                      onScan: _onScanSuccess,
                      onScanFailure: _onScanFailure,
                      onMultiScan: _onMultiScanSuccess,
                      onMultiScanFailure: _onMultiScanFailure,
                      onMultiScanModeChanged: _onMultiScanModeChanged,
                      onControllerCreated: _onControllerCreated,
                      isMultiScan: isMultiScan,
                      scanDelay: Duration(milliseconds: isMultiScan ? 50 : 500),
                      resolution: ResolutionPreset.high,
                      lensDirection: CameraLensDirection.back,
                    ),
                    if (showDebugInfo)
                      DebugInfoWidget(
                        successScans: successScans,
                        failedScans: failedScans,
                        error: isMultiScan ? multiResult?.error : result?.error,
                        duration: isMultiScan
                            ? multiResult?.duration ?? 0
                            : result?.duration ?? 0,
                        onReset: _onReset,
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
            if (kIsWeb)
              const UnsupportedPlatformWidget()
            else
              ListView(
                children: [
                  WriterWidget(
                    messages: const Messages(
                      createButton: 'Create Code',
                    ),
                    onSuccess: (result, bytes) {
                      setState(() {
                        createdCodeBytes = bytes;
                      });
                    },
                    onError: (error) {
                      _showMessage(context, 'Error: $error');
                    },
                  ),
                  if (createdCodeBytes != null)
                    Image.memory(createdCodeBytes ?? Uint8List(0), height: 400),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onControllerCreated(_, Exception? error) {
    if (error != null) {
      // Handle permission or unknown errors
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: $error');
    }
  }

  _onScanSuccess(Code? code) {
    setState(() {
      successScans++;
      result = code;
    });
  }

  _onScanFailure(Code? code) {
    setState(() {
      failedScans++;
      result = code;
    });
    if (code?.error?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: ${code?.error}');
    }
  }

  _onMultiScanSuccess(Codes codes) {
    setState(() {
      successScans++;
      multiResult = codes;
    });
  }

  _onMultiScanFailure(Codes result) {
    setState(() {
      failedScans++;
      multiResult = result;
    });
    if (result.codes.isNotEmpty == true) {
      _showMessage(context, 'Error: ${result.codes.first.error}');
    }
  }

  _onMultiScanModeChanged(bool isMultiScan) {
    setState(() {
      this.isMultiScan = isMultiScan;
    });
  }

  _showMessage(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
    );
  }

  _onReset() {
    setState(() {
      successScans = 0;
      failedScans = 0;
    });
  }
}

when i give camera permisssion, then it works as expected without any issues;
I'm using:

Xcode: Version 15.4 (15F31d)
Doctor summary (to see all details, run
flutter doctor -v): [✓]
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on macOS
14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode, develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the
web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources



Can you add below permission too and try again Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

Also can you clean and restart PC and then clean and build again. I know this is weird but for specially for mac apps this is good solution.

Also can you check below points too...
Check Plugin Dependencies

Also Ensure that all required dependencies for the camera_avfoundation plugin are correctly configured in your Flutter project. This includes the plugin itself and any platform-specific configurations.


Flutter Clean

Sometimes, stale build artifacts or conflicting dependencies can cause issues. Run flutter clean to clean up the project and then try running it again.


Probably that library your using has issue to open channeling to link native code to dart , which compiler mentioned (Unable to establish connection on channel)
